# Building Different APK with different flavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to be able to build same app with different package name. My current approach is using flavor (build variant). This works fine except that app built on different flavors replaces the other one on the device. What i want to achieve is building this same app with different flavors and not replacing same app on the same phone built with another flavor. Below is a snippet of my current approach. How can i achieve and am i doing anything wrong?

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            applicationIdSuffix ".release"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "flavor"
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            flavorDimension "flavor"
            applicationId
            "com.eample.flavor1"
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        flavor2 {
            flavorDimension "flavor"
            applicationId
            "com.example.flavor2"
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        flavor3 {
            flavorDimension "flavor"
            applicationId
            "com.example.flavor3 "
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your config seems right. But place applicationId and it's value on same line.

Comment: Yea, thanks. it works well now.